# How can I kill a process that kills the computer if it hangs?

Tags: bash, scripting, out-of-memory

I would like to write a script that detects when my Ubuntu machine hangs for more than 10 seconds, for example, and kills the offending process so I don't have to force-power-off my device.

The problem seems to be that my RAM overfills sometimes (I have 8 GB, but I'm working with RAM disks and more then one virtual/guest OS, sometimes I play a game with over 1000 entities). The RAM can't swap fast enough because my HDD is slow, but I don't want to repair that because I'll get more RAM soon.

I just want to have a script that kills a very resource-intensive process if my computer hangs. How can I go about that?

Uh, EDIT:   I sometimes can hear sound, mouse works in very most cases if hangs... But keyboard like crashed and I can't go to login-shell with alt+ctrl+cmd/windows/super F4/F5/F6
and it doesn't looks that it fixes byself (kernel is still alive, HDD makes *sometimes* noices, but I leaved it already more then an hour: no fix, HDD noices not hearable, maybe every minute one

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you mean by "hangs". Can you still move the mouse? Can you hear any sounds? Also, doesn't this go away by itself? There is already a operating system process that kills programs that are taking too much memory (it is called the OOM-killer), if the problem is indeed your RAM, if you wait for a bit it should handle it for you.

Comment: i strongly recommend NOT using ram disks larger than your actual RAM.  A ramdisk's purpose is to speed up some kinds of disk I/O, and it absolutely will not and can not do that if so much RAM is being used that it has to be swapped out which defeats the purpose.   More generally, you're trying to do too much with too few resources.  You already plan to upgrade your RAM - an excellent plan.  I recommend upgrading your HDD too, to something a lot faster....an SSD, for example.

Comment: Also, it would probably be a good idea to shut down your VMs and other non-essential tasks when you want to play resource-intensive games or applications.  And install ublock origin and umatrix to block ads and control javascript if you run a browser on that machine....and don't leave hundreds of tabs open in dozens of windows (i do that, and it wastes a lot of RAM, which is part of the reason i have 64GB in my main desktop machine. browsers are notoriously bloated memory pigs)

Comment: @cas Yes I also said I get more ram... Anyways too large ram files go into swap - nevermind. second my virtual machine was not running while playig games and I have a tuns of adblocker

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script.
`sudo swapoff -a`   will turn off the swap completely. When swap is turned off, Kernel will kill the process. Check man pages `swapoff` for more details

Comment: I relly don't like to put off swap because I'd like to create a bit too big RAM disks over 8 GB and then my computer will die.. Or is compressing enough strong? I don't think.. But I can think removing swap if I have my additonal 32 GB RAM... I'd like to have a script, also because kernel doesn't likes my computer, doesn't do his job well.. BAD KERNEL!! And apt / packagekidt isn't good too.. Removing boot screen or what? Boot Splash were set back in one of my ubuntu systems

Comment: Oh! I also have bad experience with my raspberrypi... It died building wheel for numpy. Used ALL RAM and swap file only 100 MB. Increasing swap helped, but then pip bugged snd it weren't able to create wheel!!!::::

Comment: no option to edit comment? first mistake is really in first comment and then boot splash: not setting back boot screen, just choosing a alternate one instead of the modern spinning one wich is default-set

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with 21.04...
But swapoff didn't work. Also crashed. Anyways it doesn't happen anymore (known)

For interested: set swapoff to 0 so it is like swapoff but just uses it if kernel is 'dead'
Also zramctl and zramswap might be the bad and then the system dies... But it normally just can't execute any command anymore after that happens. But for exmp. saving a libre office file works ????!!!

New knowledge:
It looks like the NVidia Drivers crashed the system as many others had that